# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application Unable to Get Python to Import Libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, anaconda, importerror

I have tried for 2 days to install Python 64-bit on my 64-bit Windows
10 PC. However, I tried Python, Anaconda, one user/ all users,
installation in C: Root/ Program Files/ etc. But I am unable to get
around this error. After online research it is some issue related to
Python not finding the 64-bit DLLs, but I couldn't locate how to
resolve this.

```
import tensorflow as tf Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File

"C:\Anaconda\envs\mango\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py",
line 24, in <module> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow 
pylint: disable=unused-import File "C:\Anaconda\envs\mango\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py",
line 47, in <module> import numpy as np File "C:\Users\Abhinav
Pandey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py",
line 142, in <module> from . import core File "C:\Users\Abhinav
Pandey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py",
line 23, in <module> WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))File
"C:\Anaconda\envs\mango\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is
not a valid Win32 application
```

Python works fine (mango)

```
C:\Users\Abhinav Pandey>python Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for
 more information.
```

pip install works fine I could install pandas, only when I import, it
gives the same error (mango)

```
C:\Users\Abhinav Pandey>pip install pandas
Collecting pandas Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/4e/9db3468e504ac9aeadb37eb32bcf0a74d063d24ad1471104bd8a7ba20c97/pandas-0.24.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas) Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas) Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in c:\users\abhinav
pandey\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pandas)
(1.16.2) Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in
c:\anaconda\envs\mango\lib\site-packages (from
python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.12.0) Installing collected
packages: pytz, python-dateutil, pandas Successfully installed
pandas-0.24.2 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2018.9
import pandas Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File
"C:\Anaconda\envs\mango\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line
13, in ?<module>
__import__(dependency) File "C:\Users\Abhinav Pandey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py",
line 142, in <module> from . import core File "C:\Users\Abhinav
Pandey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py",
line 23, in <module> WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename)) File
"C:\Anaconda\envs\mango\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is
not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: It looks like your tensorflow is 32-bit.

Comment: This happens with numpy, and every other package.

Comment: Show us the output of your installation of the libraries that are giving trouble. It is clear it didn't work properly but without a log it is hard to say why.

Comment: Your error message is consistent with a 64-bit Python interpreter attempting to load a 32-bit DLL (and has few other plausible causes). It is happening at the point where `pandas` tries to import the DLLs for `numpy`, `pytz` and `dateutil`. The import is not failing with an import error (so those modules are all there), it is failing with an OS Error (because of the DLL issue). I can't tell which DLL of which module is the wrong bitness but it is very likely to be a DLL belonging to one of those three. I would try importing `pytz` and `dateutil` in a fresh session to isolate the problem.

Comment: pytz and dateutil are importing no problem.

Comment: I am trying to understand which 32-bit DLLs are these, and how to used 64-bit DLLs in their place. It seems a package-independent issue, something generic.

Comment: It is clearly one of the `numpy` DLLs because the line of code that is failing with the OS error is loading only those 3 and the other two work. `numpy` is used by  `pandas` and `tensorflow` etc, etc, and so that is why it appears generic. If you have one DLL of the wrong bitness you might have others. But you have no evidence of that so far. Right now, your error message is pointing at only one problem module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I wasn't using Anaconda, just the latest distribution. But re-installing Python in a different location ( I had it on C:/Python37) fixed the issue.

Not sure why, but I tried on the predefined location for the installer and in C:/Program Files/Python37, and both worked for me.